# Creating foreign key on same table SQLite

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, ddl

Recently I started using SQLite (as required for my study) and I came accross a couple of restrictions of SQLite and I was wondering: can't SQLite create foreign keys on the same table? E.g. this is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Categories
(
    name varchar(20),
    parent_category varchar(20) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(name),
    FOREIGN KEY parent_category_fk(parent_category) REFERENCES Categories(name)
)
```

But it gives me an error for the foreign key when I try to execute the SQL in SQLiteStudio.

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you have the wrong syntax for the FK clause. It should be:

```
FOREIGN KEY (parent_category) REFERENCES Categories(name)
```

If you want to name the FK constraint, you do that with a prefix of the `CONSTRAINT` keyword, like this:

```
CONSTRAINT parent_category_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent_category) REFERENCES Categories(name)
```